# Suppose that $X$ is a $Binomial(n,p)$. Then the variance of $X/n$ is:

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, binomial-distribution

[image]

In my attempts, I find that variance of $x=npq$, therefore $x/n$ must be $npq/n$, which becomes, ($npq/(variance/pq)$). And variance is $npq$. So I am left with $npq/npq/pq$. And I know this is totally wrong, so I just need some help to figure this out.

Comment: In general the variance of $aX$ for a constant $a$ is $a^2$ times the variance of $X$.

Comment: I'm not sure how you were reasoning, but [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) may make your fractions more comprehensible.

Comment: You shouldn't confuse $X$ with $x.$ without distinguishing between those, you can't even understand what $\Pr(X\le x)$ means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a random variable $X$ and constant $a,V[aX]=E[(aX-E(aX))^2]=a^2V[X]$. So $V[\frac Xn]=\left(\frac1n\right)^2\times V[X]=\frac{npq}{n^2}=\frac{p(1-p)}n$, since $q=1-p$.

Comment: How did you get x/n=1/n, where did the 1 come from. Thank you though, the answer is correct

Comment: @farooq1219 Take $a=1/n$.

Comment: but why 1/n? Whats the formula behind this?

Comment: @farooq1219 I showed that the variance of $aX$ is $a^2$ times the variance of $X$. So the variance of $\frac Xn$, with $a=1/n$, is $a^2=1/n^2$ times the variance of $X$.

Comment: i get that a=1/n and so a^2 = 1/n^2, but why is there a 1? sorry im just really confused about how the 1 came to be, sorry for being a bother

Comment: You mean to say the $1$ in $1-p$?

Comment: no like the 1 in (1/n), how did we get 1/n from x/n?

Comment: $\frac Xn$ is the random variable (function) obtained by dividing $X$ by $n$, which is a constant. This can also be written as $X\times\frac1n$, similar to how $\frac23=2\times\frac13$

Comment: I understand now, thanks